# Veracrypt installation a nightmare on Jessie

Tags: software-installation

Installing VeraCrypt on my Pi 2B and can't seem to get past this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd veracrypt
pi@raspberrypi ~/veracrypt $ ls
veracrypt-1.0f-1-setup-console-raspberrypi_arm  veracrypt-1.0f-2-setup.tar.bz2
veracrypt-1.0f-1-setup-raspberrypi_arm.tar.bz2
pi@raspberrypi ~/veracrypt $ sudo apt-get install veracrypt-1.Of-1-setup-console-raspberrypi-arm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package veracrypt-1.Of-1-setup-console-raspberrypi-arm
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'veracrypt-1.Of-1-setup-console-raspberrypi-arm'
pi@raspberrypi ~/veracrypt $
```

I believe I have installed all dependencies and just don't know where to go from here. This distro is formatted for the hardfloat Jessie processors. Compiling has been suggested, but I run into errors there too and being new to Linux I'm shooting in the dark here. Should I consider using TrueCrypt or has anyone had success at installing VeraCrypt?

Comment: Have you tried this  ./veracrypt-1.0f-1-setup-console-raspberrypi_arm  instead of apt-get install

Comment: `1.Of` vs `1.0f` - see the difference?

Comment: I see the difference, but try just running the extracted file. Why are you installing of not 0

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Us newbies really appreciate it! That seems to have installed it. But there is no GUI that I can see on my desktop. Only terminal. When I type /usr/bin/veracrypt in the terminal, I get a lot of this: Usage: veracrypt [--auto-mount <str>] [--backup-headers] [--background-task] [-C] [-c] [--create-keyfile]  and a list of commands. Is it possible to get a GUI going?

Comment: The site I linked to in my answer includes how to use veracrypt from the command line. Which is the stuff you are seeing at the commandline. I could not find any evidence of GUI support for the Pi version of veracrypt.

Comment: Funny how simple it is when you know what you are doing. Thanks Steve!

Comment: it's not that bad - I grabbed the actual wxWidget 3.0 sources and compiled them myself though. SW

Comment: you can use `zulumount-cli` which is available in the raspbian repo via `apt`; it's a bit clunky to use, but works with veracrypt containers. See here for the invocation syntax: https://github.com/mhogomchungu/zuluCrypt/wiki/zuluMount-cli-howto

example mounting a file container: `sudo zuluMount-cli -K $UID -m -t vcrypt   -d myveracryptvol.vera -z /mnt/vol1`.

For unmounting use `sudo zuluMount-cli -u -d /dev/mapper/zulu....` and do NOT use `umount`.

Answer (score 2):

Per the instructions [here](https://fredfire1.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/install-veracrypt-debianwindows/).

You should install with the following command:

```
./veracrypt-1.0f-1-setup-console-raspberrypi_arm
```

not apt-get as shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following procedure to install VeraCrypt:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev makeself libwxbase3.0-0

cd ~
mkdir veracryptfiles
cd veracryptfiles
wget -L -O veracrypt-1.19-raspbian-setup.tar.bz2 https://launchpad.net/veracrypt/trunk/1.19/+download/veracrypt-1.19-raspbian-setup.tar.bz2
tar -vxjf ./veracrypt-1.19-raspbian-setup.tar.bz2
chmod +x veracrypt-1.19-setup-*

./veracrypt-1.19-setup-console-armv7
```

Based on:

https://jacekstyrylski.github.io/2017/04/02/Vera-Crypt-OSMC/

Comment: why are people down voting this? It works like a champ

Comment: @ScottWood it seems self promotion: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/promotion and that has some basic rules to follow. I guess someone can ad it,

Comment: @rene if it works, who cares what it promotes?

Comment: @ScottWood it cares if the poster is affiliated with a business that makes money with spamming their product. There is enough spam posted daily on all sites across the network to be cautious when links are added. That is why I said to edit in the affiliation, specially because you think this has value.

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get` is a part of the [Advanced Packaging Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) which is the Debian implementation of package handling. It is inherited to a lot of other Linux systems, including the well known Ubuntu, and the familiar Raspbian.

APT handles repositories - that is, lists of from where software can be downloaded - and sorts out dependencies. APT front ends `dpkg`, that handles the actual package installation.

The most common case for software installation on Linux is that the software you are requiring is already in a repository. The installation is as simple as

```
apt-get install <package>
```

However, some software has not made it into the repositories (yet), but are packaged. Then you will most probably download a package, with a file ending of `.deb`. Use `dpkg` to install it.

```
dpkg --install <package>.deb
```

Other times, like in this case, you really need software that the manufacturer has not packaged, for some reason. Then you might choose to download a source package, that will contain build instructions, or, as in this case, a custom installer, that you can execute.

All this being said, venturing out of the topic of the original question and on a more personal note, I, for one, would not trust security software that asks me to execute a binary for which I cannot see the source. I would rather use for example `gpg` with `Kgpg` or `Seahorse`.